# How to create demo project in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, demo

I was asked to create a demo project in Xcode to send it to the third-library developer so the question is: is it a special thing or I should just send him a copy of my project uploaded or zipped?

Could not find any info on "demo project" term in google or here. Thanks!